# The type or namespace name 'WorkbookEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

This code snippet i use to create a excel sheet from dataset (I parse .rtf file and get make a list of datasets). But i get error with line 3 of my code snippet

> Error: The type or namespace name 'WorkbookEngine' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument(DS);
XslCompiledTransform xt = new XslCompiledTransform();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(typeof(WorkbookEngine).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(WorkbookEngine), "ValidationReport1.xls"));
XmlTextReader xRdr = new XmlTextReader(reader);
xt.Load(xRdr, null, null);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xt.Transform(xmlDataDoc, null, sw, null);

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\ValidationReport1.xls");
myWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
myWriter.Close();
```

Comment: What is `WorkbookEngine`? I couldn't anything about it wiht Google.

Comment: **i took this code from following link** i think workbookengine is a class. link : http://itsrashid.wordpress.com/2007/05/14/export-dataset-to-excel-in-c/

Comment: _Well_, this link doesn't open because I'm at work now, you probably missing the namespace which `WorkbookEngine` belongs..

Comment: but i am just creating a public method and adding this logic with that inside my class.

Comment: Hi could u please give ur inputs on another problem?

Comment: @user1071296 If you have another question, *ask another question*, don't post a comment. That's how this site is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project has not referenced the namespace which contains the "WorkbookEngine" object.

At the top of your project you should have a list of USING lines. Add the appropiate line for your object.

Comment: I am adding the method which contains this logic within a new function inside my class. I have not created a new class for this function.

Comment: From the link you provided above it looks like they the "WorkbookEngine" is the name of your current class. 
There seems to be quite a few examples in the comments on that link you supplied.

Comment: no 'workbookEngine' is not my class name. I have a class called 'Validation_Report_2.0' and within that i created a method 'createreport' which contains the logic mentioned above.